# How to mock a package method in Go?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, mocking

Let's say I have a package with the following code:

```
package paths

type FilePath struct {
    PathA string
}

func (c FilePath) GetPathA() string {
    if err := PathExists(PathA); err != nil {
    return ""
    }
    return PathA + "foo"
}

func PathExists(p string) error {
    // call os and file methods
    return err
}
```

How do I mock out the PathExists dependency to test FilePath? Also, method `PathExists` is being used by a lot of other packages as well. (I am open to suggestions of refactoring this to make it test friendly, keeping the following pointers in mind)

I have come across a few different approaches but none of them seems intuitive or idiomatic to me.

1. Have a global variable `PE := PathExists` in the package; in `GetPathA`, call `err := PE(PathA)` and in the test overwrite `PE` with a mock method.

   Issue: If test package is something like paths_test, I will have to export `PE` which allows clients of the package to overwrite it as well.
2. Make `PathExists` a field of `FilePath` and mock the field in test.

   Issue: Clients when using the package, will have to initialize `PathExists` field, or I provide a constructor of the form `NewFilePath(PathtA string)` which initializes the fields for me. In the actual use case there are a lot of fields, hence this approach fails as well.
3. Use an interface and embed it within the struct. When client uses it initialize with the actual method and for test mock it.

   ```
   type PathExistser interface{ 
       PathExists(p string) error 
   }

   type FilePath struct{
       PathA string
       PathExister
   }

   type Actual struct{}

   func (a Actual) PathExists(p string) error {
      return PathExists(p)
   }
   ```

   Issue: Client again needs to provide the right implementation of the interface.

I have learnt of few more approaches doing something simimlar to the above options, such as make the method `PathExists` an argument for `GetPathA`, etc. All have the same concerns. Basically, I don't want the users of this package to have to figure out what should be the right input parameter to make sure the struct works as expected. Neither do I want the users to overwrite the behaviour `PathExists`.

This seems like a very straightforward problem and I seem to be missing something very funamental about go testing or mocking. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Method names are just for example. In reality `GetPathA` or `PathExists` would be way more complex.

Answer (score 4):

To address the issue from your `1.` approach, you can use an internal package which you'll then be able to import in `paths_test` but clients of your package won't be.

```golang
package paths

import (
    // ...
    "<your_module_path>/internal/osutil"
)

func PathExists(p string) error {
    return osutil.PathExists(p)
}
```

```golang
package osutil

var PathExists = func(p string) error {
    // call os and file methods
    return err
}

// Use a mutex to make sure that if you have
// multiple tests using mockPathExists and running
// in parallel you avoid the possiblity of a data race.
//
// NOTE that the mutex is only useful if *all* of your tests
// use MockPathExists. If only some do while others don't but
// still directly or indirectly cause the paths.PathExists
// function to be invoked then you still can run into a data
// race problem.
var mu sync.Mutex

func MockPathExists(mock func(p string) error) (unmock func()) {
    mu.Lock()
    original := PathExists
    PathExists = mock
    return func() {
        PathExists = original
        mu.Unlock()
    }
}
```

```golang
package paths_test

import (
    // ...
    "<your_module_path>/internal/osutil"
)

func TestPathExists(t *testing.T) {
    unmock := osutil.MockPathExists(myPathExistsMockImpl)
    defer unmock()
    // do your test
}
```

Comment: That `internal` package-level var is a nice trick!

Comment: Ah indeed, this is a nice trick! However, a developer writing code for the same library/application that has this package, can still accidentally introduce a bug by overwriting osutil.PathExists (I know I am being extremely picky, but just want to make sure I am well aware of all the pros/cons of a solution before taking it up)

Comment: If you can refer to any standard library that uses this approach or has a similar problem, it would be really help in solidifying my confidence in this approach

Comment: @kernel0707 I don't know if the std lib uses this approach. If you want to follow test patterns that are used in the std lib then you may have to drop the idea of mocks altogether as I don't think those are used much. Instead, at least in the `net` package, a lot of functions are tested using "test hooks". To your other point about dev-introduced bugs, to avoid those you should write a test that can catch such an error or if that's not possible then you do code review before merging the pull request.

Comment: @kernel0707 keep in mind that the standard library itself does have exported variables that, if they were to be changed inappropriately by some client code, could wreak havoc. In my opinion it is the job of the developer to know their dependencies well enough to not misuse them and shoot themselves in the foot. The fact that what you want is difficult and ugly, if not outright impossilbe, to implement in Go should be recognized as an indicator that you need to either loosen up on your requirements or switch to a language that provides the security mechanisms you're looking for.